# How to add "+" inside Hyperlink?

Tags: html, web, href

I want to pass C++ as my parameter in Hyperlink.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can url encode the plus character i.e. replace each plus character with: %2B

Comment: Theres more information about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Look-up what "URL Encoding" is and I think you'll find out why having a `+` character failed and why %2B works along with the meaning behind it.